# Setting Higher, Custom Resolution in Wayland Like Virtual Resolution By Radeon

Tags: xorg, grub, wayland

In Xorg, its easy to setup custom resolution by using `xrandr`.

AMD offers virtual resolution by which I can set higher resolution (For ex. Monitor supports 1920x1080, but can go upto 3840x2160 or more virtually), but utility only available for windows.

In **wayland** when I try to change video param in **grub** config file, monitor says `Out Of Range`.

I just want to increase scaling of windows, text everything to sync it to my main laptop screen, at low resolution everything appears so big as compare to my laptop screen.

Any fix will really be helpful!

Comment: "Monitor supports 1920x1080" - so obviously you can't display more pixels than physically exist.